# Is there a way to reduce the size of a video file to a specific size?

Tags: video, encoding, video-encoding

I'm trying to get a video file to be a specific number of bytes. Basically, I will have a video X of duration/fps/compression ratio x, which I will want to change the size of to be the exact same size as video Y. I want to find out if there are any possible ways to either add null data to X until it is the size Y, or re-encode it to cut it down to the size of Y.

My first thought was to create a longer video than necessary, then trim it down. However, the biggest issue with that is that it'll be super hard to trim down a video to a very specific byte count using a typical video editor. I've tried googling a solution for a while now and can't seem to come up with any ways to get this done. Is this even possible?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What problem are you actually trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Sorry, I should've considered that actually. I'll try to explain it here, but I'll put it in the post as well. Basically, I will have a video X of duration/fps/compression ratio x, which I will want to change the size of to be the exact same size as video Y. I want to find out if there are any possible ways to either add null data to X until it is the size Y, or re-encode it to cut it down to the size of Y.

Comment: Smallest unit in a video file is one frame, each frame consist of at least several kB, so no way to reach desired output just by editing (changing compression has unpredictable effect on exact size) . Based on format, you might add meta data too, that could be an option to add a long string to your file, filling up to desired size.